# Email not sending if mail body contains servers domain, email id with servers own domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, webserver, phpmailer

Pardon for the broken English.
I am facing an issue while sending email using PHP-codeigniter.

My server is hostgator. There is an email for every registration in my software.
My server stop sending the mail suddenly. I have then tried by changing all the mail content one by one like mail `subject,mail body, alt body, attachment etc`. Later I realized that in my footer there is an email address with its own domain name. 
For example lets assume my domain is `www.abcdefg.com`.
There is an email link in the footer like `"info@abcdefg.com"` when I am removing this mail from mail its sending without any error. Even I am changing the mail like `"info@abcdef.com"` or `"info@abcdefgom"` or all other combination works. But the `"info@abcdefg.com"` don't.
Also when I am using any images or any resources links like style from this domain `"abcdefg.com"` mail stops sending. 
Another problem is that I am not able to track the status of the mail sent form my Hostgator Cpanel. 
It takes me 2 days effort to find the weired issue.
I think this is not any issue with code and hope with the server. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your mail is not configured properly in Cpanel.

Comment: Have you checked that the emails simply doesn't end up in the receivers spam folder? If the emails works when you simply remove the urls from the content, I would definitely say it's not a code issue.

Comment: How the case with same domain only can be blocked?. Please tell me in detail

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson I have checked the spam folder also